# Using Gradle, how can I ensure that a command exists

Tags: groovy, build.gradle

I am using Gradle for AOSP, I would like to check if a command exists in my build environment.

```
task printCommand{
    doLast{
        def command = "git --version"
        println command.execute().text
    }
}
```

Above code run perfect, it will print the output from command "git --version".

But I try another command according to [Check if a program exists from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script)

```
task printCommand{
    doLast{
        def command = "command -v docker"
        println command.execute().text
    }
}
```

It always show the wrong message like this.

> Execution failed for task ':printCommand'.
>   java.io.IOException: **Cannot run program "command": error=2**, No such file or directory

Why I can't use "command -v docker" in this way ?

Are there any better ways to check if a command exists in Gradle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`command` is a builtin bash command, not a binary.

groovy's `String.execute` will start a process. The binary that the process is started from has to be given fully qualified (e.g. `"/usr/bin/docker --version"`) or must be found on your `$PATH` (or `%PATH%`)

Comment: What do you mean by "fully qualified" ?

Comment: Work for me. `task printCommand{
    doLast{
        exec{
            def command = "command -v docker"
            executable "bash" args "-l", "-c", command
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 2):

Get back to the subject, I find the way to ensure that a command exists while using Gradle, this code can avoid Gradle script terminated by non-zero exitValue, and print the appropriate information.

```
task checkCommand{
    doLast{
        result = exec{
            def command = "command -v docker"
            ignoreExitValue = true
            executable "bash" args "-l", "-c", command
        }
        if(result.getExitValue()==0){
            println "Has Docker"
        }else{
            print "No Docker"
        }
    }
}
```

Update 2019/02/23

If you get this error:

> Could not set unknown property 'result' for task ':checkCommand' of
>   type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask

Add `def` in front of `result` will fix this issue.